# Is there (Delphi style) align property for .NET WPF panels?

Tags: c#, wpf, delphi

Delphi (Object Pascal) panels have align property with values as client / bottop / top / left / right. Is there similar property (or cobination of other properties with the same similar effect) for .NET WPF panels? How align WPF panel to be expanded over entire window (as client)? How to position ther panels at the bottom or top border of the window (bottom, top)?

Comment: Your question is far too broad. Please research WPF `UIElement` properties like `HorizontalAlignment`, `VerticalAlignment`, `SharedSizeGroup` for grids, and of course the various types of container elements. If after doing some research and _trying_ something, please post a new question with a good [mcve] showing what you've tried and a precise description of what that code does and what you want it to do instead.

Comment: There is `DockPanel` which allows you to set the attached property `DockPanel.Dock` on children to align them to top, bottom, left, or right. Note that the last child typically fills the remaining space in the panel. I have no idea if this is similar to a Delphi panel.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Ah, thanks for picking that up. It has been a while. That said, I don't think that this is too broad. Delphi has a simple property on controls that lets you indicate whether that control should automatically align itself to the top, bottom, right, left or client of the parent control. All the OP wants to know is if there is something similar in .NET  WPF.

Comment: @Graymatter: there are lots of ways in WPF to achieve that. It seems to me that the `DockPanel` container might work, but it's impossible to know with such a broadly-stated question. The OP presumably has a _specific_ scenario in mind, but without the details, there's no way to know whether that specific scenario is correctly or best addressed by any specific WPF technique.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: the OP is asking for several kinds of alignment: client, bottom, top, right, left. his question is if there is a **simple way**, like in Delphi, like one simple property. I guess the answer is: no, you can achieve this in several ways, but not with one simple property. Or am I wrong? He is not asking for the many less simple ways to do this, AFAICT.

Comment: @Rudy: it's clear the OP wants "one simple property", but it's not clear what he wants the "one simple property" for. I'm not convinced the marked duplicate is the correct one (I voted "too broad", not "duplicate"). But I do think it's likely `DockPanel` is a fruitful direction to investigate and, frankly, once the `DockPanel` is part of the XAML, it _is_ "one simple property" to then control the location of the child.

Comment: @Peter: for the same purpose as in Delphi: to set the alignment of a component WRT its parent control, being one of left, right, bottom, top, client or none. It is probably very clear to those who actually know Delphi. There is nothing " too broad" about this. "I don't quite understand because I don't know Delphi" is not the same as "too broad", IMO. He didn't use the `delphi` tag for nothing.

Comment: @Peter: If I understand this right, it is possible in a DockPanel, but not generally for every control placed on another. Then a good answer would be: "No, there isn't a general way, but you can put it on a DockPanel, which can do this, see http://www.wpftutorial.net/DockPanel.html". I don't think this is a duplicate.

Comment: @Rudy: _"I don't think this is a duplicate"_ -- you can think that all you want, fine by me. Take it up with Ken White, who is the one who ultimately closed this question (and who clearly _is_ an expert in Delphi, by the way). That said, if you yourself agree that `DockPanel` is as close as the OP is going to get, then we might quibble about _which_ `DockPanel` answer is in fact the best duplicate choice, but surely a question asking how to essentially do the same thing, i.e. dock/align controls to the edges of a container, is still a duplicate.

Comment: He is not asking **how**, just if it can be done **the same way as in Delphi**. Obviously **not**, because it can only be done on a DockPanel, not generally for every control on any other control or directly on a form. That is not a duplicate, no matter what Ken thinks. The "duplicate" already uses a DockPanel and just asks how to align. That is not how it is done in Delphi. In Delphi, you don't need to put the control on a special panel to achieve it.